# Python. String Index Out Of Range. Ceasar Cipher

Tags: python, string, recursion

I am having trouble with my Ceasar Chiper Program.

This is what I have so far:

```
def enchiper(s,n):
    '''
    This function takes a string(s) and an integer(n) and
    shifts the elements of s around the alphabet
    '''
    Alpha1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    Alpha2 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    if 1 == len(s):
        if 'a' <= s[0] <= 'z':
            spot1 = myIndex(s[0],Alpha1)
            x = spot1 + n
            if 26 < x:
                y = x - 26
                return Alpha1[y]
            else:
                return Alpha1[x]
        elif 'A' <= s[0] <= 'Z':
            spot1 = myIndex(s[0],Alpha2)
            x = spot1 + n
            if 26 < x:
                y = x - 26
                return Alpha2[y]
            else:
                return Alpha2[x]
        else:
            return s[0]
    else:
        if 'a' <= s[0] <= 'z':
            spot1 = myIndex(s[0],Alpha1)
            y = spot1 + n
            if 26 < y:
                x = y - 26
                return Alpha1[x] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
            else:
                return Alpha1[y] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
        elif 'A' <= s[0] <= 'Z':
            spot1 = myIndex(s[0],Alpha2)
            y = spot1 + n
            if 26 < y:
                x = y - 26
                return Alpha2[x] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
            else:
                return Alpha2[y] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
        else:
            return s[0] + enchiper(s[1:],n)

def myIndex(element, sequence):
    ''' returns the number of times that an element appears in a list
    returns a random number from 0 to length of sequence if the element
    does not appear in the list
    Input: element is either an integer or string
    sequence is a list of strings and integers
    '''
    if 0 == len(sequence):
        return 0
    elif sequence[0] == element:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + myIndex(element, sequence[1:])
```

The program works pretty well, some times the strings I enter give me a "string index out of range". For example:

```
>>> enchiper('hello',15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    enchiper('hello',15)
  File "/Users/spencerzanardi/Documents/hw3pr2.py", line 41, in enchiper
    return Alpha1[y] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
  File "/Users/spencerzanardi/Documents/hw3pr2.py", line 41, in enchiper
    return Alpha1[y] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
  File "/Users/spencerzanardi/Documents/hw3pr2.py", line 41, in enchiper
    return Alpha1[y] + enchiper(s[1:],n)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Also, I have use to recursion in my program. I am not allowed to use loops

Comment: put a `try: ... except IndexError: ...` around line 41 and then you can print out the values of Alpha1, s, y, and n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst this does not do upper/lower case (although a quick upper or lower and it would)

```
def encyp(string,shift):
        Alpha1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        c=string[0]
        pos=Alpha1.find(c)
        pos=(pos+shift)%26
        if len(string)==1:
            return Alpha1[pos]
        else:
            return encyp(string[0], shift) +  encyp(string[1:], shift)
```

You can make this shorter ...

Comment: Just so you now, `Alpha1` (and2) is already defined in python:

`import string`, `string.ascii_lowercase`, `print string.ascii_uppercase`



So it is bad practice to use `string` as variable. Nice code though.

Comment: @MaxChrétien many thanks for the info regarding string module. Agreed about the name of the variable. Regards T.

Answer (score 0):

I debuged your program, when I print `y` in `Alpha1[y]` I got 26. Indeed `Alpha1` (or 2) start index at 0. Try to change all your occurences of `if 26 < x:` and `if 26 < y:` by `if 26 <= x:` and `if 26 <= y:` and it should work.

**Edit**

Not your question but your program failed when the first `n` is bigger than 26, you should consider using a modulo at the beginning of your function. (e.g `n %= 26`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the index 26, while the indices of your arrays `Alpha1` and `Alpha2` go from 0 to 25. In the particular call `enchiper('hello',15)`, the problem is that the letter `l` is at position 11. When you add 15 you get exactly 26. Then, the condition `26 < y` will **not** be satisfied, and therefore you will try to return `Alpha1[26]`, which does not exist. If you change every occurrence of `something > 26` by `something >= 26` your code shouold work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def encipher(s, n):
   diff = ord('Z') - ord('A')
   if len(s) == 1:
      num = ord(s)
      num += n % diff

      if s.isupper():
         if num > ord('Z'):
            num -= diff
         elif num < ord('A'):
            num += diff
      elif s.islower():
         if num > ord('z'):
            num -= diff
         elif num < ord('a'):
            num += diff
      return chr(num)

   return encipher(s[0], n) + encipher(s[1:], n)
```

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.